# Add delimiter to a url, to extract different values

Tags: python, regex, django

I am developing a website right now, what I am trying to do is, whenever user enters his email to reset the password, rather than using the built-in tokens.py module in Django, I have implemented my own module that uses Cryptographic signing from Django, to generate a unique token which can be then passed in the url and render the required view.

The url mapping I have created is

```
url(r'^set_password/(?P<uid64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]{2}-[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]{6}-[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]{27})/$','accounts.views.set_password_confirm',name='set_password_confirm')
```

The regex I have created works fine when the delimiter used to separate the token is '-', but when I try to use a delimiter other than '-', the regex doesn't work.

Sample url is: `http://mywebsite.com/accounts/set_password/MTE/PQ-1aDbis-PNTp8XOiTASTWhcg1Er9URnCOYs/`

I have delimited the token 'PQ-1aDbis-PNTp8XOiTASTWhcg1Er9URnCOYs' using '-', what I want is if I use some other delimiter other than '-', the regex should work.

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can be explicit about the delimiter and list the possible delimiters inside square brackets:

```
(?P<token>[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]{2}[\-_][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]{6}[\-_][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]{27})
```

Here we are setting the delimiter to be `-` or `_`.